# Scope variable dont update after executive a service inside scope function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When i execute a scope function and try update the values after execute a service, the data doesn't update.

Inside the function, the return of service shows correctly.

The code below is my controller code:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyControllerCtrl', function ($scope, $sce, $location, $routeParams, ClientService) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.returnClient = {};
    $scope.row = {id: false};
    $scope.rowClient = {name: ''};

    $scope.postClient = function () {
        ClientService.post($scope.rowClient, function (data) {
            var item = {};

            if (data.error) {
                showError(data.message);
            } else {
                showSuccess(data.message);

                item = {
                    id: data.id,
                    text: $scope.rowClient.name
                };

                $scope.returnClient = item;
                $scope.row.codClient = item.id;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

The service code:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('ClientService', function ClientService($http) {
    'use strict';

    this.post = function (row, callback) {
        try {
            $http.post(getSiteUrl('client/create'), row).success(callback).error(function () {
                showError('Error.');
            });
        } catch (errorPost) {
            showError('Error.');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you post `ClientService.post` code?

Comment: @dfsq Service code posted.

Comment: Where is `$scope.rowClient` defined? I see you passing it into `ClientService.post()` and accessing its `.nome` property, but I don't see you initializing it anywhere.

Comment: @JLRishe, code updated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

The HTML contained twice the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use angular Resources.It's the best way to work with RestFull.If you use ngResource,You don't have to declare a function on "this" or something else.Resource has prefect url navigation.You can create functions with different methods,different urls and more,more.